# Get Ember View from jQuery object

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I know how to construct a jQuery object from an Ember view which is in the DOM:

```
App.myView = Ember.View.extend({
  elementId: "my_view",

  didInsertElement: function(){
    console.log(this.$().attr('id'))  // outputs 'my_view'
  }
});


<!-- HTML output -->

<div id="my_view">
   <!--  ...   -->
</div>
```

How about doing the inverse. Given a jQuery object, how do I get the corresponding Ember View object.

```
function(selector){
   $el = $(selector);
   // ???
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
function getClosestEmberView($el) {
  var id = $el.closest('.ember-view').attr('id');
  if (!id) return;
  if (Ember.View.views.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    return Ember.View.views[id];
  }
}
```

Comment: how about getting a component instance from dom element? -- I notice it has no id. Should I specify one somehow?

Comment: @shaunc: I tested the above method on a component. Since `Component` is a `View` subclass, it *should* have an id and be present in `Ember.View.views`.

Comment: As of ember 1.13, getting the view must be done through the view registry: `container.lookup('-view-registry:main')[id]`